# Analyze Datasets (Data Management) - what is the output?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase

I recently completed a [Analyze Datasets](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000014z000000) procedure on my ArcGIS 10.1 SDE. However, I could not find a tangible output to review.

Does anyone know where I can find the output?

Comment: Have you looked at the menu option GeoProcessing > Results? Sometimes tools write messages but have no obvious output, worth a look

Comment: @Hornbydd - I didn't even think of that. I ran it using model builder as part of a larger analysis and compression. So in this case it does not populate the results window. I am going to run it again as an individual geoprocess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analyze Datasets updates database statistics, it doesn't provide on output such as a text file or FC.